# Passing Data from JSON file to html

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have written the following Server.js code

```
var http = require('http'); // Import Node.js core module

var GreensKiosk = require('./GreensKiosk');
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) { // create web server
// Set CORS headers
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Request-Method', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');

if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end();
    return;
}

if (req.url == '/') { // check the URL of the current request
    // set response header
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    // set response content
    res.write('<html><body><p>Greens Kiosk API.</p></body></html>');
    res.end();
}
else if (req.url == "/products") { // check the URL of the current request
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    res.write(JSON.stringify(GreensKiosk.getItems()));
    res.end();
}
else if (req.url == "/products/fruits") {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    res.write(JSON.stringify(GreensKiosk.getItems('fruits')));
    res.end();
}
else if (req.url == '/products/vegetables') {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    res.write(JSON.stringify(GreensKiosk.getItems('vegetables')));
}
});
 server.listen(3000);
```

I have another GreensKiosk.js file with an array of items like so

```
let products = [
{
 name: 'Mangoes',
 category: 'fruits'
},
{
 name: 'Apples',
 category: 'fruits'
},
{
 name: 'Bananas',
 category: 'fruits'
},
{
 name: 'Oranges',
 category: 'fruits'
},
{
 name: 'Grapes',
 category: 'fruits'
},
{
 name: 'Kales',
 category: 'vegetables'
},
{
 name: 'Onions',
 category: 'vegetables'
},
{
 name: 'Tomatoes',
 category: 'vegetables'
},
{
 name: 'Cabbages',
 category: 'vegetables'
}
]
```

I would like to parse the items to a HTML file based on the URL as dictated on the Server.js
I am looking into an html of a list nature. In this way the items are displayed for each set of list.

I am new to Node js and would really love some insights into this

```
    <ul id="fruList">
        <!--fruits here-->
    </ul>
    <h3>vegetables</h3>
    <ul id="vegList">
        <!--vegetables here-->
    </ul>
```

Comment: In the client-side you should make two xhr requests to access fruits and vegetables and then for each item in array create li element `let item = document.createElement("li")` and assign name `item.innerHTML = name` and append it to the list `listlink.appendChild(item)`

Comment: Kindly clarify.

Comment: your have to accept data from server by client making xhr request and then you can manipulate data and insert it into your html

Answer (score 0):

if you know you're going to need this file, then you can read it synchronously, as in:

```
var items = require('./items.json');
```

If you have lots of different lists you'll need and you won't always need this list, you'll need to separate your data into a separate rest api. but let's assume you don't need a separate rest api. if you want to do it asynchronously, use fs and fs.readFile. btw your data in the file isn't json, it's just a plain ol js object. in json, the attribute names will have double quotes. to convert your json data into a js object, use var arrItems = JSON.parse(items). To separate items by type, use:

```
var fruits = arrItems.filter(i => i.category === 'fruits');
```

You might want to look into a templating library like mustache that will help you convert arrays into html.

Comment: I am trying to navigate to localhost:3000/products but I keep running into this error `TypeError: GreensKiosk.getItems is not a function`

Comment: as far asi can see, GreenKiosk doesn't exist in your code, and neither does getItems. you haven't defined these things anywhere. so it would imo be easier to import the data from a static json file and filter it.

Comment: On my original question the array `let products` is the GreensKiok.js is my static js file